# Dynamically configure grid of all sub-slaves tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a table-type tkinter gui program, something with a structure like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3T9s.png)

In this picture, there are 2 types of Frame: a header frame (black) and a data frame (blue). In the data frames, columns 1 and 2 change their size dynamically, depending on the length of the data.

I want to ask if once the width of a column of the data frame changes, is there any way to update the widths of the columns in other data frames and the header frame to match with the widths of the columns in the data frames.

So suppose column 1 of frame 2 increases its width, the column 1 of header frame, frame 0 and frame 1 should change to align with frame 2's column 1's new width as well.

I hope I made my question clear

Answer (score 1):

If this is a simple design with few lines of data not requiring scrollbars etc. the easiest way is to not divide the headers and data rows into different fields. Just grid everything and it will adjust automatically:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

data_list = [('No.', 'Name', 'Data'),
             (1, 'Amazon', 'Books'),
             (2, 'Python', 'Programming language')]

for index, data in enumerate(data_list):
    a = Label(root, text=data[0], bg='khaki')
    a.grid(row=index, column=0, sticky='e', pady=(5,0), padx=(5,0))
    b = Label(root, text=data[1], bg='khaki')
    b.grid(row=index, column=1, sticky='w', pady=(5,0), padx=(5,0))
    c = Label(root, text=data[2], bg='khaki')
    c.grid(row=index, column=2, sticky='w', pady=(5,0), padx=(5,0))

root.mainloop()
```

If it's large amounts of data, scrollbars etc. you shoult investigate treeview.